# Is there a more efficient way to do this if/else?

Tags: ruby

Is there a better or more efficient way to do this?

```
if not params[:date]
   @date = Date.today.to_s
else
  @date = params[:date]     
end
```

Comment: `not` should not be used for boolean logic, only control flow; use `!` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
@date = params[:date] || Date.today
```

And if you want to make `Date.today` a string then do `Date.today.to_s` as per comments :)

Comment: You're missing the `to_s` after `today`.

Answer (score 0):

I would it this way (I'm supposing this is in Rails):

```
@date = params[:date].presence || Date.today.to_s
```

The presence method checks if the params[:date] is not nil and not empty and then it returns the value, so it is generally safer than just checking for nil.

As The Tin Man noted, if you aren't in Rails and you don't want to require active_support, you could just monkey patch the Object class:

```
class Object
  def blank?
    respond_to?(:empty?) ? empty? : !self
  end

  def present?
    !blank?
  end

  def presence
    self if present?
  end
end
```

I find these three methods very useful in daily Ruby coding.

Comment: Don't assume Ruby code is using Rails.  You can assume Rails code is using Ruby though.

Comment: Well, it's dealing with params and such.. Anyhow, I guess you could require acive_support for all the sugary methods such as present?, blank? and presence which I find very convenient in everyday coding.

Comment: `params` is a pale hint. It can mean the surrounding code has a hash named `params`. If you are assuming Rails, and it isn't, then you should show how to cherry-pick just the needed Active Support methods.